# SQL Join instead of UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

I have the following tables:

```
Table T1
--------------------------
ZID   | NAME 
------------------------
1     | Test 

Table C1 
--------------------------
ZID   | VALUE1 
------------------------
1     | A 
1     | B

Table S1 
--------------------------
ZID   | VALUE2 
------------------------
1     | C 
1     | D
```

I would like a select query to fetch the values below

```
----------------------------------
ZID   | NAME  | VALUE1  | VALUE2  
----------------------------------
1     | Test  |    A    |   null 
1     | Test  |    B    |   null 
1     | Test  |   null  |    C 
1     | Test  |   null  |    D
```

I am able to achieve the above by using a `UNION` by faking a column in each select as below.

```
SELECT
    ZID,
    NAME,
    VALUE1,
    NULL AS VALUE2
FROM
    T1
    LEFT JOIN C1 ON (
        T1.ZID = C1.ZID
    )
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT
    ZID,
    NAME,
    NULL AS VALUE1,
    VALUE2
FROM
    T1
    LEFT JOIN S1 ON (
        T1.ZID = S1.ZID
    )
);
```

Would it be possible to retrieve data as above in a single select using JOINS? I have tried using left join and however, I end up with a Cartesian product of data in the results.

Comment: Gordon's answer does what you ask in a clever way. But I'd expect your `UNION ALL` of two `LEFT JOIN`'s (with table-qualified `zid` fixing the syntax) to be faster in many cases. Don't see the reason to rule out `UNION`? Aside: Postgres does not require any of the parentheses in your query.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Yes, the parentheses are for my benefit. It helps me understand better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use:

```
select t1.*, c1.value1, s1.value2
from c1 full join
     s1
     on false join
     t1
     on t1.id in (c1.id, s1.id)
```

A `full join` on `false` is a lot like `union all`.

Comment: [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/72b5f/15) demonstrating this (may also help others verify if their answers).

Answer (score 1):

Query will be something like:

```
SELECT ZID, NAME, VALUE1, VALUE2
FROM T1, C1, S1;
```

Comment: That should be `LEFT OUTER JOIN S1`.

Comment: Since there is no relationship between C1 and S1, it will still be a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Union will give you more rows.  Join will give you more columns.   If you want to join them to get one set of rows with all columns, you need to specify which rows go together. For example, if you do not specify which C1 row goes with which S1 row, it matches each to all of them, and gives the product you do not want.

Define the relationship in the on clause, and it will do what you want.

Comment: could you please post an example for the on clause?

Comment: Since you only have 1 value fro ZID, there is no good way with the data presented to specify which row from S1 correlates with which row from C1.  Data more representative of your use case may help.

Comment: If the ZID was the correlating item, select * from T1 left join C1 on T1.ZID=C1.ZID left join S1 on T1.ZID=S1.ZID;

Comment: If it would be always matching rows on every table, select * from T1,C1,S1 where T1.ZID=C1.ZID and T1.ZID=S1.ZID.

Comment: ZID is foreign key in C1 and S1, however a JOIN on them does not help. I still get a cartesian product

Comment: That is because all of them have the same value.   Make a unique index on ZID in each table, and it will help you by preventing you from making multiple rows for the same ZID.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `UNION` to add rows. You can put the join on the outside of the `UNION` to avoid having to do it twice:

```sql
SELECT
    ZID,
    NAME,
    VALUE1,
    NULL AS VALUE2

FROM
    T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ZID, VALUE1, NULL AS VALUE2
        FROM C1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ZID, NULL AS VALUE1, VALUE2
        FROM S1 
) Merged ON T1.ZID = Merged.ZID
```